# Word VBA - insert more than one type of text

Tags: vba, ms-word

To all,

I am trying to automate a Word document. To do this I want to insert some text. The normal code I would use (for a header) is:

```
Selection.TypeText Text:="This is Text"
Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
```

However, I want to add multiple lines of different styles. So, I have the following code:

```
Sub createtest()        
    insertheading1 ("This is heading 1")
    insertheading2 ("This is subheading 1")
End Sub

Function insertheading1(Text1)
    Selection.TypeText Text:=Text1 & Chr(11)
    Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
End Function

Function insertheading2(Text1)
    Selection.TypeText Text:=Text1 & Chr(11)
    Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 2")
End Function
```

So, the intention is to add one line as a Heading 1 and then a second line as Heading 2 (a subheading). But what happens it that the second bit changes the first line so that they are both of the Heading 2 style.

Can anyone help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, for me, Word 2010 that's right.
You have to add a paragraph.

```
Function insertheading1(Text1)
    Selection.TypeText Text:=Text1
    Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading1)
    Selection.TypeParagraph
End Function

Function insertheading2(Text1)
    Selection.TypeText Text:=Text1
    Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading2)
End Function
```